# Finding the base in which $54/4=13$ is a true statement

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was given for a homework assignment:

$$\frac {54} 4 = 13$$

The goal is to find the base of the three numbers (they share the same base), I was given the answer by the TA of 6, but I didn't learn how to get from point a to point b.
Is there anyone that could explain the answer to me?

I got to this point in understanding:

$$(5r^1 + 4r^0)/(4r^0) = (1r^1 + 3r^0)$$

I could do this with other questions, but I don't know how to get to the final answer of 6.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The 6 is wrong. Your method is perfect.

Comment: Shoot, I should have reduced the exponents :/ That would have helped a lot. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can rearrange this to get $54 = 13 \cdot 4$. Now if we're in base $r$, this means that

$$5r + 4 = (1r + 3) \cdot 4 \implies 5r + 4 = 4r + 12 \implies r = 8$$

As a check,

$(54)_8 = 5 \cdot 8 + 4 = 44$ in base $10$, while $(13)_8 \cdot 4 = (8 + 3) \cdot 4 = 44$ in base $10$ as well.